# Debugging in Visual Studio 2010: cxx0030 expression cannot be evaluated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am debugging quite a large project in C++, with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and from some point on, the debugger shows mostly 
`CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated`
and sometimes
`CXX0017: Error: Symbol "" not found` instead of the values of variables.

All the objects, data structures, fields, variables that the IDE debugger claims to be not evaluated, actually ARE evaluated, since I can debug further and some computations happen with those "unevaluated" values afterwards...

The project is built with `Debug` option, `x64`.

I am new to the IDE and also the language, so I am kind of lost.

What could it be? Some wrong debugging options? Could it be a mismatch between the debugged software and the built code inside the IDE(this is quite improbable but I start believing in ghosts now...). Something in the build properties? Could it be a wrong thread that I debug(but some field do have evaluated values...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I found to my problem as a description is [this issue on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131147)

I performed the below answer,

> Turn off PCH usage. This avoids the problem altogether.
>   but **in vain.**

**EDIT:**
In the end it turned out there were differences in the versions of `.pdb` debug file and the `.exe` since they were not exactly the same revision. I was getting `Symbols cannot be loaded` error, visible in the Modules view while debugging.

There were two possible solutions:

1. equalize exactly the revisions of the debugged software and the checked out code and add the `application_name.pdb` file that is produced in the build to the bin folder where the debugged `application_name.exe` lived, so that the debugger could see them
2. substitute the `application_name.exe` from the build to the software (and hope nothing breaks) and also add `application_name.pdb` file in the same folder.